# Why is Selenium throwing an unable to locate element for LKDN Sales Nav Login

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running the code below and keep getting an "Unable to locate Element" response, even though I'm using the correct element ID. Any feedback would be really appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time


#LOGGING INTO LINKEDIN
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\webdriver\chromedriver.exe")
# This instance will be used to log into LinkedIn
# Opening linkedIn's login page
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/sales/login")
# waiting for the page to load

# entering username
username = driver.find_element("id","username")
# In case of an error, try changing the element
# tag used here.
# Enter Your Email Address
username.send_keys("*****")
# entering password
pword = driver.find_element("id","password")
# In case of an error, try changing the element
# tag used here.
# Enter Your Password
pword.send_keys("******")       
# Clicking on the log in button
# Format (syntax) of writing XPath -->
# //tagname[@attribute='value']
driver.find_element("xpath","//button[@type='submit']").click()
# In case of an error, try changing the
# XPath used here
```

I'm trying to login to LinkedIn Sales Navigator with Selenium, but I can't get it to work properly. I keep getting an unable to locate element error.

Answer (score 0):

The login fields are inside an iframe, so it is first necessary to switch to that:

```
iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe.authentication-iframe")))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
username = driver.find_element(By.ID,"username")
username.send_keys("*****")
# entering password
pword = driver.find_element(By.ID,"password")
pword.send_keys("******")       
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@type='submit']").click()
driver.switch_to.default_content() 
# Allow time to see impact before closing
time.sleep(5)
```